# SimpleInjector MvcSitemapProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using

VS2013 MVC5, 
SimpleInjector 2.4.1
MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.SimpleInjector.Modules 4.4.10

and I'm getting the following error when calling 'Verify' on the container

> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type `IAttributeAssemblyProvider` failed. The registered delegate for type `IAttributeAssemblyProvider` threw an exception. The constructor of the type `AttributeAssemblyProvider` contains the parameter of type `IEnumerable<String>` with name 'includeAssemblies' that is not registered. Please ensure `IEnumerable<String>` is registered in the container, or change the constructor of `AttributeAssemblyProvider`.

The array it is referencing is :

```
string[] includeAssembliesForScan = new string[] { "MyProject" };
```

and this is what seems to be the culprit :

```
        container.RegisterSingle<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider>(() => 
            container.GetInstance<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>()
            .Create(includeAssembliesForScan));
```

The signature for the create method is :

```
public MvcSiteMapProvider.Builder.ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider Create(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> includeAssemblies)
    Member of MvcSiteMapProvider.Builder.ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory
```

I think the IAttributeAssemblyProvider is being registered as per below

```
// Single implementations of interface with matching name (minus the "I").
            CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions(
                (interfaceType, implementationType) => container.RegisterSingle(interfaceType, implementationType),
                new Assembly[] { siteMapProviderAssembly },
                allAssemblies,
                excludeTypes,
                string.Empty);
```

since :

```
  public class AttributeAssemblyProvider  : IAttributeAssemblyProvider
```

and the ctor is :

```
public AttributeAssemblyProvider(
            IEnumerable<string> includeAssemblies,
            IEnumerable<string> excludeAssemblies)
        {...}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

stack trace is :

> at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyIfAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[]
>   producersToVerify)    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyIfAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()    at
>   SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()    at
>   MyProject.App_Start.SimpleInjectorInitializer.Intialise() in
>   \App_Start\SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs:line 54    at
>   MyProject.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in \Global.asax.cs:line
>   16

Comment: How does the registration for `IAttributeAssemblyProvider` look like?

Comment: There isn't an explicit registration with the container of IAttributeAssemblyProvider that I can find, if that's what you mean. I've just taken the default code from the MvcSitemapProvider Simpleinjector NuGet.

Comment: Take a look in the source code what that package is doing. It is probably doing that registration.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: looking to get a stack trace.. in the meantime, just realised CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions wasn't one of yours, sorry

Comment: And the stack trace of the inner exception(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest versions of the external DI config files don't automatically update when you upgrade if you have changed them. Be sure you have merged in the latest versions of [CommonConventions.cs](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/Shared/DI/CommonConventions.cs) and [MvcSiteMapProviderContainerInitializer.cs](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/SimpleInjector/DI/SimpleInjector/MvcSiteMapProviderContainerInitializer.cs) from the master branch (this is to be done manually, but it helps a lot if you use a diff tool to quickly see the changes). You can also view the [releases list](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases) to see the various points where updates were done to the DI configuration with direct links to the diff on GitHub.

The latest version of CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions excludes auto-registration of any types that have a string parameter in the constructor (which AttributeAssemblyProvider does), so be sure you have merged the latest changes of that file into your project.

Of course, if all else fails you can add `typeof(AttributeAssemblyProvider)` to the `excludeTypes` array and it will no longer be auto-registered. It is not supposed to be because it has a factory class that instantiates it named AttributeAssemblyProviderFactory.

Also, if you are not using MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute to register nodes, it is not necessary to have it in your configuration at all. Removing it will make your SiteMap load a little faster.

To remove it, change this...

```
container.RegisterSingle<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider>(() => container.GetInstance<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProviderFactory>()
    .Create(includeAssembliesForScan));

// Register the sitemap builders
container.RegisterSingle<ISiteMapBuilder>(() => container.GetInstance<SiteMapBuilderFactory>()
    .Create(new CompositeSiteMapNodeProvider(container.GetInstance<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>(), container.GetInstance<ReflectionSiteMapNodeProvider>())));
```

To this...

```
// Register the sitemap builders
container.RegisterSingle<ISiteMapBuilder>(() => container.GetInstance<SiteMapBuilderFactory>()
    .Create(container.GetInstance<XmlSiteMapNodeProvider>()));
```

This is exactly what the "MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" web.config setting does when set to "false" when you are using the internal DI container.

Comment: The string exclusion in CommonConventions didn't work..but adding the type to excluded types did  Thanks